# Formatting of formatted text in print case and activiy audit

Tags: custom-fields, civicase

I'm sure this shoudl be fairly straight forward.  I think i'm looking in the wrong place.

When I try to print the report of a case (civicrm/case/report/print?) or undertake an activity audit of a case, any text that has been entered usinjg the WYSIWYG editor is displayed as raw text.  So any paragraphs are enclosed within

brackets etc.

Practically, this prevents these functions being used as the printed reports are nearly illegible (due to no line breaks and lots of angle brackets everywhere).

Hope this is clear and someone's got a quick solution.

I'm thinking i'll need to recreate these functions as a complete drupal view of the case, but would appreciate any other suggestions / approaches

Comment: It seems ok on the public demo. What version and platform are you using? Maybe in an older version there is some double-html escaping.

Comment: I've replicated it on the public demo. [link to example print case on test site](http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/case/report/print?all=1&redact=0&cid=128&caseID=1&asn=standard_timeline)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see - a custom field, not the main details field.

A couple things I think. There is a security issue with not escaping the fields, so in that sense it is being correct to escape the brackets etc, but better would be some type of sanitizing that leaves formatting but removes malicious parts. I'm not sure if this is the job of the wysiwyg editor itself or the civi code that handles the data.

Comment: I think i'll stick with some drupal views and Jasper Reports for the time being.  Sounds like it's not as straight forward as i thought.
Would this be the same reason why it also happens with the activity audit?