# HTML tags showing in Activity details

Tags: contacts, activity

This seems to have been an issue before.
[Formatting tags shown in activity view](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9487/formatting-tags-shown-in-activity-view)
Has this been resolved because I am still having an issue with this. I am not on the current version.
If there has not been a fix for this - is there a work around?
CivicCRM: 4.7.2
Drupal: 7.43

Thank you
Casey

Answer (score 1):

A work around I use is to use simple text area instead of CKEditor.

It should be fixed in 4.7.5 according to [this issue](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17978).